# How to ignore the case sensitivity in solr query

Tags: solr, case-insensitive, solr-query-syntax

I have a database that consist of Names and locations. I am searching for names using case insensitivity **USING SOLR**. However I am not able to find any way I can do that. 
For example:
I have a list of Names:

Rajeev
rajeev
raj
Raj

when i search for **cname:raj*** i get the following 
rajeev
raj

What do i do to get Rajeev and Raj also.

Answer (score 4):

You should add a new filter **solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory** to convert everything to a lowercase , this should apply to index and query.

> Analyzers are components that pre-process input text at index time
>   and/or at search time. It's important to use the same or similar
>   analyzers that process text in a compatible manner at index and query
>   time. For example, if an indexing analyzer lowercases words, then the
>   query analyzer should do the same to enable finding the indexed words.

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Analyzers

**An example:**

**Schema.xml**

```
<field name="Name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Where **text_general** type

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    tokenizerFactory="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: All my fields are of type string. Does method apply to string type as well ??

Comment: @RajeevRajvaidya you should change type string to something else.By default type string doesn't use lowercase filter  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true"/>

Comment: @Oyeme, I have a data driven schema config. How do I go about with that for case-insensitive indexing and querying